# Delete record only from parent entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my project i have 2 entities related @OneToMany and @ManyToOne.
Check these pictures -

[image]
[image]

***My problem***-when i delete record from *Supplies* also delete records from *Products* but i don't wont it.If i remove *CascadeType.ALL* and then try this opertion again there will be an error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shop`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `FK65gu3e053fcnl70hwq8vp7b2g` FOREIGN KEY (`supplies`) REFERENCES `supplies` (`id`))

How resolve this problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh,after 30 minutes of thinking i solved it. I just added this code in my delete method

```
@Override
public void deleteSupply(Long id) {
    Supplies supplies = supplyRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    Set<Products> productsList = supplies.getProducts();
    productsList.forEach(products -> products.setSupplies(null));

    supplyRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```